# Can't switch SCNView/UIViewControllers properly to prevent memory buildup

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, scenekit

I have a very linear app that uses a Navigation controller to go through a series of View Controllers.  All segues are handled in the storyboard and set to "Push" (that's the only way I can get the navigation controller to work...)

Start with a 'menu' VC with options, select one and it takes you to another VC.  Sometimes the next VC is another menu (more detailed) but sometimes the VC is an SCNView that shows an SCNNode.  **Navigating** through the VCs is working perfectly, thanks to the Navigation Controller.

The problem comes whenever you go **to** one of the SCNViews and then **back out** (to a menu or previous VC).  Particularly, switching from menu to SCNView, back to menu, back to **same** SCNView, over and over builds up memory until the app crashes.

ARC seems to not be releasing the SCNNodes/SCNViews when navigating out of them.  **Every** SCNNode/Scene/View I set up as weak AND I've tried all kinds of combinations of the following code in each/all the VCs:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(true)


    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I put this at the end of each VC but it still seems that the SCNNodes are getting retained and the memory builds up until it crashes.

How can I clear the SCNNodes when I exit the VC?  Since I declare everything as weak inside ViewDidLoad, I can't call/set anything in the ViewWillDisappear func since it's outside of that.

Comment: Do you have some other references to those views causing a retain cycle?

Comment: Not that I can see (or that I'm aware of)! It's a very linear app, I set up each ViewController for n it's own each with buttons that either go forward to an SCNView or then back to the menu. Unless the VCs are somehow being retained globally I just can't see why they won't release the memory.